# Does ORDER BY affect multiple WHERE conditions?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to implement paging on a table named `posts`, and I'm using the columns `time_created` and `post_id` as the delimiter for the pages.

It's possible that multiple posts are created at the exact same time, so when retrieving the next page, I need to get all the remaining posts created at a specific time, and then get posts created before that time.

My concern is that [postgres doesn't care about the order of WHERE conditions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115723/are-where-clauses-applied-in-the-order-they-are-written), and since I have 2 conditions separated by an OR, the following query may only use the second condition to fulfill the LIMIT requirement.

My question is: Does the ORDER BY clause guarantee that the first condition I provided `(time_created = $1 AND post_id < $2)` will be executed first since `time_created = $1` should logically come before `time_created < $1` when ordered by descending order?

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE (time_created = $1 AND post_id < $2) OR time_created < $1 
ORDER BY time_created DESC, post_id DESC
limit 50;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will be executed in three steps:

1. Eliminate rows which do not satisfy conditions in the `WHERE` clause.
2. Order remaing rows by expression(s) in the `ORDER BY` clause.
3. Get first 50 rows according to the `LIMIT`.

So the order does not affect filtering.

If you run `EXPLAIN ANALYSE <your query>` you will get something like this:

```
                                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=430.71..430.84 rows=50 width=12) (actual time=1.727..1.730 rows=50 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=430.71..445.82 rows=6042 width=12) (actual time=1.726..1.727 rows=50 loops=1)
         Sort Key: time_created DESC, post_id DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
         ->  Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..230.00 rows=6042 width=12) (actual time=0.010..1.329 rows=6027 loops=1)
               Filter: (((time_created = '2018-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (post_id < 1111)) OR (time_created < '2018-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 3973
 Planning time: 0.493 ms
 Execution time: 1.759 ms
(9 rows)
```

which can be interpreted as the three steps described above.